# Infer second parameter from first parameter based on object

Tags: typescript, type-inference, typescript-generics

I have an interface, called FormState, that I use to type check my state in react. I'm trying to create a function that will update the state based on key, and automatically infer the correct type from the interface, using the key passed. Here's my interface (and state for reference):

```
interface FormState {
    username: string
    password: string
    auto_login: boolean
    access_code: string
    method: number
    use_proxy: boolean
    ignore_invalid_certificates: boolean
}

const [state, setState] = useState<FormState>({
    /* state here */
})
```

and function:

```
function updateState<T extends keyof FormState> (key: keyof FormState, value: FormState[T]): void {
    setState(old => {
        old[key as any] = value
        return old
    })
}
```

I want to be able to call this function, say with the first parameter as "auto_login", and for it already infer my second parameter as boolean, as based off of my interface.

My current implementation doesn't work - it infers each of the possible types, rather than the correct type. I also don't think I should have to pass through a type parameter, but if it's needed then sure.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, I'm stupid. I realized I could just use `key: T`, instead of `key: keyof FormState`, which solved my problem:

```
function updateState<T extends keyof FormState> (key: T, value: FormState[T]): void {
    setState(old => {
        old[key as any] = value
        return old
    })
}
```